# Pass const Key_Type& to operator[] of std::map

Tags: c++, dictionary, std

Why I can't pass `const Key_Type&` to operator[] of std::map? I have done this and it compiled but in runtime `std::bad_alloc` exception was thrown:

```
std::map<std::string, int> myMap;

const std::string& f(const std::string& groupA, const std::string& groupB) 
{ 
    return groupA > groupB ? groupA + groupB : groupB + groupA;
}

std::cout << myMap[f("a", "b")];
```

Comment: Think about this: How do you reference *an expression* (like `groupA + groupB`)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are returning a reference to a temporary in function `const std::string& f(const std::string& groupA, const std::string& groupB)`

```
return groupA > groupB ? groupA + groupB : groupB + groupA;
```

The `+` operator returns a temporary value which is being then returned by reference.

Hence changing the return type return by value (`const std::string`) solves the problem.

As pointed out by @Narek how Herb Sutter explains using const ref to temporary variables. But the problem statement we have does not match what Sutter discusses. To explain more I have created a small program. The program explains the problem and the resolution:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>

/*
std::map<std::string, int> myMap;

const std::string& f(const std::string& groupA, const std::string& groupB) 
{ 
    return groupA > groupB ? groupA + groupB : groupB + groupA;
}*/


struct X{

  int member;


  X():member(0){
      std::cout<<"X ctr "<<std::endl;
  }

  X(const X& rhs){

      std::cout<<"X copy ctr "<<std::endl;
  }

  ~X(){

      std::cout<<"X dtr"<<std::endl;
      member = -1;
  }
};

void f2(const X& obj){

    std::cout<<"func "<<obj.member<<std::endl;

}   

const X& f3(){ 
    return X(); 
}

X f4(){ 
    return X(); //ideally not a good idea, exception is
    //http://herbsutter.com/2008/01/01/gotw-88-a-candidate-for-the-most-important-const/
}

int main()
{
    /*  myMap["ba"] = 1;
    std::cout <<"key "<< f("a", "b")<<std::endl;
    std::cout << myMap[f("a", "b")]<<std::endl;*/

    std::cout << "-----Faulty Case-----------"<<std::endl;

    //reference returned by f3 is local to f3 call and 
    //is destructed as soon as f3() is out of stack
    //and hence the reference in f2() is not valid
    f2( f3() );

    std::cout <<std::endl<< "-----Correct way-----------"<<std::endl;

    //A temporary object is returned by f4 which is then referred by reference in f2.
    //This reference is alive in stack of f2 and hence can be used inside 
    //f2 with valid results.
    //As explained in following article, the refernce should remain
    //alive in stack to use temporary objects.
    //http://herbsutter.com/2008/01/01/gotw-88-a-candidate-for-the-most-important-const/
    f2( f4() );

    //note in previous expression, f4 returns by value but still copy ctr is not invoked,
    //this I believe is Return Value Optimization (might be compiler dependent)

    return 0;
}
```

Output of this program:

```
main.cpp: In function â��const X& f3()â��:
main.cpp:41:14: warning: returning reference to temporary [-Wreturn-local-addr]
     return X(); 
              ^

Executing the program....
$demo 
-----Faulty Case-----------
X ctr 
X dtr
func -1

-----Correct way-----------
X ctr 
func 0
X dtr
```

I hope this clears the clouds.

Comment: But when I use the temporary reference returned by the function by assigning it to `const Key_Type&` the life of the temporary object should be lengthened, right? http://herbsutter.com/2008/01/01/gotw-88-a-candidate-for-the-most-important-const/.

Comment: The value returned by the function which acts as KEY  is just used to get the VALUE from map, so u don't have to worry about life. If u want to store persistence, then do store it in a named variable.

Comment: if it is not about the presistence of the temporary value returned by the reference, then what is the problem?

Comment: In ur existing solution u are returning reference to a value which goes out of scope once func call returns.

Comment: @Narek the lifetime is not extended in the case where the binding is to the return value of the function

Comment: @MattMcNabb didn't get you. What you mean?

Comment: @Narek You are thinking of the rule where a temporary *object* can have its lifetime extended by being bound to a const reference. But your function does not return an object, so there is nothing to extend.  (And the temporary object that exists within `f` does not have lifetime extended outside of `f`)

Comment: @MattMcNabb `return groupA > groupB ? groupA + groupB : groupB + groupA;` does not create a temporary object?

Comment: @Narek the expression `groupA + groupB` creates a temporary string . (We know it is temporary because it does not have a name).  Same for `groupB + groupA`.

Comment: @MattMcNabb You wrote "But your function does not return an object, so there is nothing to extend." So now my function returns temporary object or no? :)

Comment: @Narek your function returns a reference to a temporary object. (as stated by the first line of this answer). A reference is not an object.

Answer (score 0):

Changing the definition of f from `const std::string& f`to `const std::string f` fixes the problem, because that way the temporary result of (A + B) gets copied in the return variable. Otherwise a pointer to a temporary variable is returned, the ownership of the memory allocated is ill-defined, and things go wrong.

Comment: Yes, it does. Actually I have done the same to remove the exception, but I don't understand why I have an exception.

Comment: Asking questions or clarifications should be done in comments. Answers should state things, and preferably give the reason behind the problem and solution.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg I guess he will edit his answer to the real one.