# C++ temporary object bound to argument and return value const references

Tags: c++

I cannot get a clear idea of whether this is legal, even after looking at related questions on SO and reading the C++03 standard page 192 (http://cs.nyu.edu/courses/fall11/CSCI-GA.2110-003/documents/c++2003std.pdf). Is this legal and safe:

```
const MyClass& f(const MyClass& arg) {
  return arg;
}

void some_other_function() {
  const MyClass& reference = f(MyClass());
  // Use reference.
}
```

It seems to me that it is.

Comment: This should be the same as the famous "most important const" discussed here: herbsutter.com/2008/01/01/gotw-88-a-candidate-for-the-most-important-const/ There should be no dangling reference.

Comment: @jogojapan yes that is what I think. Except that C++ is quirky and maybe the fact that the temp has been created outside the function changes things. We are looking here at extension of lifetime after the const reference being assigned to another const reference, it is not obvious to me from the standard that this is valid.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As far as I know, you can't do this. While binding a temporary to a const reference is legal C++(and lengthens the lifetime of that temporary -- [see GOTW 88](http://herbsutter.com/2008/01/01/gotw-88-a-candidate-for-the-most-important-const/)), further binding a const ref to another const ref doesn't lengthen the lifetime of that temporary.

The quote from page 192([C++03 standard](http://cs.nyu.edu/courses/fall11/CSCI-GA.2110-003/documents/c++2003std.pdf)):

> A temporary bound to a reference parameter in a function call (5.2.2)
>   persists until the completion of the full expression containing the
>   call

I think the standard is pretty explicit that using reference after `// Use reference.` is invalid. I modified your snippet to check it(Mac OS X, clang: `Apple LLVM version 5.1 (clang-503.0.40) (based on LLVM 3.4svn)`):

```
#include <iostream>

struct MyClass
{
    ~MyClass()
    {
        std::cout << "~MyClass()" << std::endl;
    }
};

const MyClass& f(const MyClass& arg) {
    std::cout << "f()" << std::endl;
    return arg;
}

int main() {
    const MyClass& reference = f(MyClass());
    std::cout << "main()" << std::endl;
}
```

It outputs:

```
f()
~MyClass()
main()
```

In other words, unless both me and clang developers are misinterpreting the C++ standard, it is illegal.

Comment: One reason why the lifetime of this temporary isn't extended is that the definition of `f` might be unknown to the compiler at the point where it's called, for example if it's defined in another Translation Unit (= source file). If the compiler doesn't see its implementation, it cannot know that it returns the very same object passed in as a reference.

Answer (score 5):

I was unable to get a clear interpretation from the standard, so I decided to check what's the *de facto* standard. The following code:

```
#include <cstdio>

struct MyClass
{
    MyClass() { printf("constructor\n"); }
    ~MyClass() { printf("destructor\n");  }
    MyClass(const MyClass&) { printf("copy\n"); }
    MyClass(MyClass&&) { printf("move\n"); }
};

const MyClass& f(const MyClass& arg) {
    return arg;
}

int main()
{
    {
        printf("before construction\n");
        const MyClass& reference = f(MyClass());
        printf("after construction\n");   
    }
    printf("outside scope\n");
}
```

Yields:

```
before construction
constructor
destructor
after construction
outside scope
```

For MSVC, clang and g++. Seems it is not legal according to our main compiler suppliers.

Answer (score 3):

This question is similar to following question: [Pass const Key_Type& to operator[] of std::map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24990370/pass-const-key-type-to-operator-of-stdmap/24990727#24990727)

The code below explains what exactly is happening

```
#include <iostream>


struct MyClass{

  int member;


  MyClass():member(0){
      std::cout<<"MyClass ctr "<<std::endl;
  }

  MyClass(const MyClass& rhs){

      std::cout<<"MyClass copy ctr "<<std::endl;
  }

  ~MyClass(){

      std::cout<<"MyClass dtr"<<std::endl;
      member = -1;
  }
};

void f2(const MyClass& obj){

    std::cout<<"func "<<obj.member<<std::endl;

}   

const MyClass& f3(){ 
    return MyClass(); 
}

MyClass f4(){ 
    return MyClass(); //ideally not a good idea, exception is
    //http://herbsutter.com/2008/01/01/gotw-88-a-candidate-for-the-most-important-const/
}

int main()
{
    std::cout << "-----Faulty Case-----------"<<std::endl;

    //reference returned by f3 is local to f3 call and 
    //is destructed as soon as f3() is out of stack
    //and hence the reference in f2() is not valid
    f2( f3() );

    std::cout <<std::endl<< "-----Correct way-----------"<<std::endl;

    //A temporary object is returned by f4 which is then referred by reference in f2.
    //This reference is alive in stack of f2 and hence can be used inside 
    //f2 with valid results.
    //As explained in following article, the refernce should remain
    //alive in stack to use temporary objects.
    //http://herbsutter.com/2008/01/01/gotw-88-a-candidate-for-the-most-important-const/
    f2( f4() );

    //note in previous expression, f4 returns by value but still copy ctr is not invoked,
    //this I believe is Return Value Optimization (might be compiler dependent)

    return 0;
}
```

Output of this program would be:

```
Executing the program....
$demo 
-----Faulty Case-----------
MyClass ctr 
MyClass dtr
func -1

-----Correct way-----------
MyClass ctr 
func 0
MyClass dtr
```